# User mapper in ForMember in automapper

Tags: .net, automapper

I wondering if it is possible to “sub map” mapped objects in ForMemeber. I have a mapping for class a to b configured. Then I have two new classes I need to map c and d, but the structure is different so I have to use ForMember to map configure mapping between them. But both c and d has properties with classes that users a in source and b in destination. Is there a way to say use the already configured mapping for the inner a to b mapping for the properties in c and d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, you have something like

```cs
public class a
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public class b
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class c
{
    public a Baz { get; set; }
}

public class d
{
    public b Qux { get; set; }
}
```

And you want to the properties in classes `c` and `d` to be mapped without having to redefine the mapping for `a` and `b`?

If so, you get that by default. Something like this should do it:

```cs
public static class AutoMapperConfigurator
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<a, b>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Bar, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Foo));
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<c, d>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Qux, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Baz));
        AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

If you instead meant something else, please update your question to clarify.